# How to Insert Line Breaks by Calling join() Function in VimScript

Tags: vim

I have a list in VimScript:

```
let demo = ["First Line", "Second Line", "Third Line"]
```

Now, I try to call `join(demo, "\r")` to insert line breaks between items. The result I expect is:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
```

However, the *REAL* result is:

```
First Line<0d>Second Line<0d>Third Line
```

How should I call `join()` to insert line breaks between items?

--- EDIT ---

Here is the actual code sample:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cc call InitCPPSrcFile("//")
 
function InitCPPSrcFile(comment_flag)
    let &display = "truncate,uhex"
    let l:demo = [a:comment_flag . "First Line", "Second Line", "Third Line"]
    call setline(1, join(l:demo, "\n" . a:comment_flag))
endfunction
```

Comment: Some things in Vim make a lot of sense and are relatively intuitive but line breaks are not them. In this context, you are supposed to use `\n`, not `\r`.

Comment: @romainl I have tried `\n`. The result is `First Line<00>Second Line<00>Third Line`. By the way, I call `join()` in `BufNewFile` triggered function.

Comment: Where do you get that "result"? Can we see a minimal reproducible example? We are lacking context, here.

Comment: @romainl The code is [here](https://pastebin.com/uWQjwzX2) and the result is `//First Line<00>//Second Line<00>//Third Line` in Terminal when run `vim demo.cc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the `<0d>` and `<00>` are a bit confusing but that's because of `set display+=uhex`. Without it, they are displayed as `^M` and `^@`, "carriage return" and "null", respectively, which is slightly easier to reason about.

Anyway, it is not `join()` that is playing with your nerves but `setline()`:

```
:call setline(1, "foo\nbar")
:1#
    1 foo^@bar
```

I am not sure how to fix this or even it is worth fixing, because `setline()` will do what you expect with a list as argument:

```
:call setline(1, ["foo", "bar"])
:1,2#
    1 foo
    2 bar
```

In this case, `:help join()` is messy anyway, because of what it forces you to do in order to insert the `//` *before* every line:

```
 item item item
     ^    ^        " where join() inserts stuff
 item item item
^    ^    ^        " where you want to insert stuff
```

I would suggest `:help map()` instead, which allows you to manipulate each item exactly how you want:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cc call InitCPPSrcFile("//")

function InitCPPSrcFile(comment_flag)
    let &display = "truncate,uhex"
    let l:demo = ["First Line", "Second Line", "Third Line"]
    call setline(1, map(l:demo, { idx, val -> a:comment_flag .. val }))
endfunction
```

[image: *.cc]